# API Integration osclass

Tags: php, api, integration, osclass

I have found a few people looking for solutions to osclass which doesnt seem to be massively popular as far as plugins go so hope that my issue will help others too.

I have created an php API which integrates with Interspire Email Marketer (IEM).

When someone signs up to become an advertiser at an osclass site the following API contacts Interspire Email Marketers XML.PHP and adds the subscriber to the list.

I'm a little stuck as to what to add to the SUBMIT button of Osclass registration form. Heres the API:

```
<?PHP

// CHECK AUTHORIZATION
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------    -----
if ($MailingListAuth == true) {

/
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------    -----
$s_name = check_type('s_name');
$s_email = check_type('s_email');
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$xml = '<xmlrequest>
<username>MyIEMUserName</username>
<usertoken>b331be663b16ae7atolkeiias9f7hgkg7ff2f1d</usertoken>
<requesttype>subscribers</requesttype>
<requestmethod>AddSubscriberToList</requestmethod>

<details>
<emailaddress>'.$s_email.'</emailaddress>
<mailinglist>2</mailinglist>
<format>html</format>
<confirmed>yes</confirmed>

<customfields>

<item>
<fieldid>2</fieldid>
<value>'.$s_name.'</value>
</item>

</customfields>

</details>
</xmlrequest>
';

$ch = curl_init('https://example.com/mail/xml.php'); //CHANGE TO THE PATH OF     YOUR IEM INSTALLATION
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$result = @curl_exec($ch);
if($result === false) {die("Error performing request");}
//var_dump($result); //for debugging purposes
//Example of how to display returned data
$xml_doc = simplexml_load_string($result);
if ($xml_doc->status == 'SUCCESS' && empty($xml_doc->data)) {die('Status is     success. Empty response.');}
if ($xml_doc->status == 'SUCCESS') {
    echo 'Response: <br />';
    var_dump($xml_doc->data);
} else {
    echo 'Error is '. $xml_doc->errormessage;
}

}

?>
```

Heres the osclass form button code

```
<button type="submit" class="ui-button ui-button-middle ui-button-main"><?    php _e("Create", 'bender'); ?></button>
```

I'm not sure how I call the API php page so that it gets sent to IEM and adds the subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

You have hooks and plugins, you could use the 'user_register_completed' hook

for example

```
function IEM_subscribe($userId) {
    $user = User::newInstance()->findByPrimaryKey($userId);
    //YOUR CODE HERE
    // user's email is in $user['s_email']
    // user's name is in $user['s_name']
}
osc_add_hook('user_register_completed', 'IEM_subscribe');
```

This function will be called AFTER the user is registered, is you want to called it before, use the 'pre_user_post' hook.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It sounds a little complicated but Il give it a go. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks @CONEJO but thats a little beyond my abilities. I dont understand where that code goes and how the IEM mailing list code fits into the snippet you added? Adding all the code to the page would make my admin username and token visible if you view page source, which seems a little insecure? The code I added at the tope is an actual page and so dont understand how that can be done with the code you sent. Im new to osclass and so maybe nee to lear a littel more but I dont really want to become as greater coder as yourself and some of the others on here.   Thanks anyway.